# lattice, connect points only if the connection has a positive slope

Tags: r, plot, lattice

is there a comfortable way to connect points only if the connection has a positive slope? (otherwise the function should behave exactly as xyplot(...))

```
library(lattice)

dat <- data.frame(x=1:10,y=sample(1:10))

xyplot(y ~ x, data=dat,
       panel = function(x, y,...) { 
         panel.xyplot(x, y, type="o",...)
       }
)
```

so the result shoud be a plot like this, but without crossed lines:

[image]

Thank you
Christof

Comment: While Roland's solution is very good,  I have to ask whether this is the best way to get your message to your reader.  Can you explain **why** you want to display any lines at all?  The standard rule is to plot points only for experimental data.  I'd suggest, instead of lines, identifying every instance where `y[j]>y[j-1]`  and plotting those points in a different color to indicate the "incoming" slope.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
dat <- dat[order(dat[, "x"]),]
dat$group <- cumsum(c(1, diff(dat$y) < 0))


xyplot(y ~ x, data = dat, groups = group,
       panel = function(x, y,...) { 
         panel.xyplot(x, y, type = "o", col = trellis.par.get("plot.line")$col, ...)
       }
)
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: brilliant, thank you very much. I try to find out if I can use a similar solution if there is a additional grouping factor.